# How to use Keystore to connect to SSL enabled IBM MQ using NodeJS

Tags: node.js, ibm-mq

I need to connect to IBM MQ on cloud which is SSL enabled with mutual authentication from NodeJS. Because of some restrictions at MQ side I am unable to connect to this IBM MQ using Native keydb approach. When i try to connect i get error. My client confirmed that I wont be able to connect to MQ using keydb(native approach)

```
MQ call failed in CONNX: MQCC = MQCC_FAILED [2] MQRC = MQRC_HOST_NOT_AVAILABLE [2538]
```

I saw official documentation of ibmmq node library which mentions that MQI based client like Node, Python etc  needs to use keydb. I am able to connect to this IBM MQ using Java (Keystore).
I would like to know if there is a way to connect to IBM MQ from NodeJS using keystore which i used to connect from Java.

Comment: Which version of MQ client are you using?

Answer (score 2):

You can't directly use the jks file with the ibmmq node library.

You can convert the jks to a kdb using these commands:

```
runmqckm -keydb -convert -db key.jks -new_format kdb
runmqckm -keydb -stashpw -db key.kdb
```

The first command will create two files:

```
key.kdb
key.rdb
```

The second command will create the stash file:

```
key.sth
```

Both commands will prompt you for the jks password.

Comment: Hi Josh, i tried this, but i get same error. Basically, IBM MQ that is configured by my client does not supports connections in native approach.

Comment: You have not provided any information on what error.   Please **edit** your question and add the error and some sample code that produces the error.

Comment: Updated. Basically, I want to connect to ibm mq through node JS using keystore like how  I do in java.

Comment: Can you show sample of how you connect in Java successfully as well as how you are attempting to connect with the ibmmq node library that fails.  The 2538 error indicates you can't reach the MQ server via TCP/IP not a TLS issue.   Can you check the `AMQERR01.LOG` on the client machine and report any errors that coincide with the 2538 error.

Comment: Ok, i am using official IBM MQ java code sample to conenct. I am able to telnet IBM MQ on port and even do netcat. Even i tred using MQ client too; utility but same error. No errors in  AMQERR01.LOG.

Comment: Are you checking the AMQERR01.LOG on the client machine or on the queue manager machine?  I would expect none on the queue manager but there should be something on the client side.   Is this a full mq client install or a redist client?  Which version of the client?

Comment: This tutorial (second part) on mutual authentication shows how to create the `.kdb`. It uses it for Java, but it the `.kdb` should work with Node.js.  Although going by your error, there is something else amiss in your Node.js code, that is pointing at the wrong location. https://developer.ibm.com/components/ibm-mq/tutorials/configuring-mutual-tls-authentication-java-messaging-app/  Al

Comment: @Rajjy please note I had a critical typo in my original answer.   The command is `runmqckm` not `runmqakm`.